# Ошибка "already initialized constant SLEEP_TIME" в задачах

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня в каждой задаче внутри `namespace` прописана константа `SLEEP_TIME`. У каждой задачи своя константа со своим значением.

Почему когда я запускаю `task1`, я вижу эти ошибки?

```
/app/lib/tasks/task1.rake:11: warning: already initialized constant SLEEP_TIME
/app/lib/tasks/task2.rake:9: warning: previous definition of SLEEP_TIME was here
/app/lib/tasks/task3.rake:11: warning: already initialized constant SLEEP_TIME
/app/lib/tasks/task1.rake:11: warning: previous definition of SLEEP_TIME was here
```

Соответственно, если использовать не одну, а больше констант, то и этих ошибок будет больше.

Почему при запуске одной задачи Rails лезет в другие? Можно это как-то "отключить"?

Comment: "внутри `namespace`" -- каком-таком? Который [из Rake](https://apidock.com/ruby/Rake/DSL/namespace)?

Comment: @D-side он самый.

Comment: @D-side только что заметил эти же ошибки при деплое, например, у всех `rake assets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гем rake (Ruby make) используется не только в Ruby on Rails но и для выполнения зависимых задач в чистом Ruby. Поэтому rake не следует рельсовым соглашениям автозагрузки, названия rake-задач не обязаны совпадать с названиями файлов. Чтобы найти задачу, rake требуется загрузить все rake-файлы. Так как rake-задачи не помещены в модули или классы, константа `SLEEP_TIME` оказывается в глобальной области видимости и постоянно переопределяется.

Избавляться от такого поведения не имеет смысла, так как: rake-задачи часто зависят друг от друга

```
task foo: :baz do
  ...
end
```

В Ruby on Rails rake-задачи могут зависеть от Rails-окружения

```
task questions: :environment do
  ...
end
```

Т.е. изолировать задачи друг от друга принципиально не получится — rake предназначен для их связывания, как например, это происходит во время деплоя. Обратите внимание на [capflow](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/) — десяток задач связаны в единое дерево, изолируете задачи — разрушите процедуру деплоя.

Вместо этого лучше изолировать константы в модули с уникальными названиями:

```
namespace :hello do
  module Hello
    SLEEP_TIME = 100
  end
  desc 'hello'
  task :hello do
    puts Hello::SLEEP_TIME
  end
end
```

Причем модули имеет смысл вынести за пределы rake-задач, например, в папку `lib`.